# webapp2 post request is not accepting json through POSTMAN

Tags: json, http-post, webapp2

Here is my webapp2 code

```
class SendMessage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        messageToId = self.request.POST.get("messageToId")
        message = self.request.POST.get("message")
        logging.info(messageToId)
```

When I hit above method in my html using

```
        var url = 'http://myapp.appspot.com/sendmessage';

        var messageToId = document.getElementById("messageToId").value;
        var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
        var jsonDta =  {
                messageToId : messageToId,
                message : message
            };
        $.post(url, jsonDta, function(data, status) {
        });
```

This is working fine.But when I try it with postman(selected post request -> raw data -> JSON/application) then it is not able to get json data and prints None in developer console. What is the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you do not use a json payload in your post.
It is a normal form post. To post json you have to `JSON.stringify(jsonDta)`

If you send json, your handler looks like this:

```
import json
....

class SendMessage(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):

        json_string = self.request.body
        dict_object = json.loads(json_string)

        messageToId = dict_object['messageToId']
        message = dict_object.get('message', default='')
        logging.info(messageToId)
```